# Does anyone know why the content of my page is showing twice?

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with the template code.

```
<div class="layout">
    <?php if ( ! Wrapper\display_sidebar() ) :
        echo '<div class="container">';
    endif; ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'page' );
        get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'layout-blocks' );
    endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ( ! Wrapper\display_sidebar() ) :
        echo '</div>';
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Inside layout-blocks, I have this

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'layout_blocks' ) ) {
    while ( have_rows( 'layout_blocks' ) ) : the_row();
        $layout = get_row_layout();
        $layout = str_replace( array( '_', 'layout_' ), '-', $layout );
        if ( true !== get_sub_field( 'hide' ) ) :
            get_template_part( 'templates/layout', $layout );
        endif;
    endwhile;
} else {
    get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'page' );
}
```

I don't know if for some reason, it's not taking the condition and displaying the content again

Comment: Show twice? The only thing discernible you *execute* twice is `get_template_part()`. Could the problem be narrowed down there?

Comment: the built in function `get_template_part()` is for single use only, meaning that you should create a full package of file of what you want to display in a single template file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply removing

```
get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'page' );
```